# Format specifications for real numbers

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I would like to print some real numbers to a log file.  To make them easy to read I would like them to all have the same width.  I know these numbers will range from 0 to 4095.75 so I tried this:

```
$display("expected= %4.2f, actual= %4.2f", expected, actual)
```

What I expected to see was this:

```
expected=   12.25, actual=   12.75 
expected= 4093.25, actual= 4094.75
```

But what I got in was this:

```
expected= 12.25, actual= 12.75 
expected= 4093.25, actual= 4094.75
```

How do I force the width of the value above the decimal point to be 4 characters?  Section **21.2.1.3 Size of displayed data** of the LRM is silent on %f.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `%7` works for your values with 2 simulators I tried:

```
module tb;

real expected, actual;

initial begin
    expected = 12.25; actual=   12.75;
    $display("expected= %7.2f, actual= %7.2f", expected, actual);
    expected= 4093.25; actual= 4094.75;
    $display("expected= %7.2f, actual= %7.2f", expected, actual);
    #5 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
expected=   12.25, actual=   12.75
expected= 4093.25, actual= 4094.75
```

Comment: Stupid me assuming that the first number referred to what happened before the decimal point instead of the total length of the field.

Comment: @nguthrie: That was just a wild guess on my part.  The IEEE Std 1800-2012 does not explicity show the %X.Yf syntax.  It just alludes to the C language.  Behavior might be system-dependent, too.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible also to specify how many number we want to see for floating point vars, after comma:

```
    `uvm_info(get_type_name(), $sformatf("tslot_start=%.3f, tslot_start_tolerance=%.2f", 
tslot_start, tslot_start_tolerance), UVM_LOW)
```